# Disable rotation keyboard sensors?

Tags: keyboard, hp

I have an HP Spectre x360, which is a convertible that can flip into a tablet.  I'm running 18.04, with MATE.  It has rotation sensors to disable the keyboard and trackpad when it's flipped into the tablet mode, or even when it's just placed on its side.  I would like to turn this off, or have a script to toggle it on and off; I frequently like to use my laptop while lying on my side, and having the keyboard and touchpad turn off all the time is annoying.  Is there a way to do this?  I tried removing iio-sensor-proxy, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the iio-sensor-proxy instead of removing it?

I think it would fix the problem and you can reverse it whenever you want.

```
sudo systemctl stop iio-sensor-proxy.service
sudo systemctl disable iio-sensor-proxy.service
```